# MySQL: Query for most recent entires of distict fields set prior to specified date

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the scenario.

I have a table 'components':

```
| id | sys_id  | name  | serial_num | model_num | date       |
+----+---------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+ 
|  4 | CZMIL01 | comp1 | 0101       | ABAB      | 2010-02-25 |
|  3 | CZMIL01 | comp2 | 0011       | AABB      | 2010-02-03 |
|  8 | CZMIL02 | comp2 | 0001       | AAAB      | 2010-02-03 |
|  5 | CZMIL02 | comp1 | 0010       | AABA      | 2010-01-14 | 
|  6 | CZMIL02 | comp2 | 0011       | AABB      | 2010-01-14 |
|  7 | CZMIL02 | comp3 | 0100       | ABAA      | 2010-01-14 |
|  1 | CZMIL01 | comp1 | 0000       | AAAA      | 2010-01-01 |
|  2 | CZMIL01 | comp2 | 0001       | AAAB      | 2010-01-01 |
+----+---------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Where 'date' specifies when a component was put into a system 'sys_id'. Only one component of a given name is in a system at a time; so if two entries have the same component name, the one with the later date has replaced the one with the earlier date.

Desired Solution:

I need a query which tells me which components where in a given system on a given date.

For example, if I specified CZMIL01 and 2010-02-05, the result would be:

```
| id | sys_id  | name  | serial_num | model_num | date       |
+----+---------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+ 
|  1 | CZMIL01 | comp1 | 0000       | AAAA      | 2010-01-01 |
|  3 | CZMIL01 | comp2 | 0011       | AABB      | 2010-02-03 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select c.*
from components c
where c.date = (select max(c2.date)
                from components c2
                where c2.sys_id = c.sys_id and
                      c2.serial_num = c.serial_num and
                      c2.date <= '2010-02-05'
               );
```

You can add a `where` condition for a particular `sys_id` in the outer `where`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

When I use the above query (with the outer WHERE) I get rows 1, 2, and 3 from the components table. However, the component in entry 2 is no longer in the system, as it has been replaced by the component in entry 3 on '2010-02'03'.

Comment: Probably you just have to remove `c2.serial_num = c.serial_num` from subquery.

Comment: Got it! I put 'name' in place of serial_num! Thanks michaJIS!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but this is a simple query.

```
Declare @sys_id as varchar(50), @date as datetime
Select @sys_id = 'CZMIL01', @date = '2010-02-05'

SELECT id, sys_id, name, serial_num, model_num, [date]
FROM components
WHERE sys_id = @sys_id and [date] <= @date
```

Looks to me like your results should also include id 2 (CZMIL01 on 1/1/2010)
Also, date 2/5/2010 inclusive then use <=, date exclusive then use <